# Trying to use multimerge in R and get error message

Tags: r

I am trying to do [multimerge][1] but it keep getting an error message

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 119, 75, 78, 71, 74
```

I thought merge would be able to handle different row numbers - which is why I am using merge rather than cbind (and the fact that i need each row in each column to match specifically to a rat ID).

Here is what I've got:

```
datalist = list()

modeldf <- d %>%
  select("Dam", "Rat", "Group", "Sex", "CS.NCS")

datalist <- list(modeldf) #adding to list

for (i in colnames(d[c(6:47)])) { 
  
#STUFF IN FOR LOOP
    
    resultcolumn <- newdf %>% #final result dataframe
      select("Rat", all_of(i))
    
    datalist[[i]] <- resultcolumn #adding result dataframe to list
}

resultsdf <- merge(datalist, by="Rat", all.x=TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

The datalist is a perfect list of dataframes, the resultcolumn outputs a perfect dataframe (i checked with `class()`).

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

edit: typo
[1]: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Orcs/vignettes/merge.html

Answer (score 0):

turns out i'm an idiot. solved by installing [this](https://github.com/vapniks/mergeutils) package and using multimerge